# "loadHTMLString:baseURL:" iPhone SDK

Tags: ios

I'm coding up my firs iPhone app..

How can I use "loadHTMLString:baseURL:" to send the user to a view called "pagetwo.m"?

Comment: be more specific, what kind of view is it? is it called from a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume pagetwo.m is a UIViewController subclass, right? You can't send a user to view with loadHTMLString:baseURL: since that's a UIWebView's method to load html page into webview. You will need something like:

```
[self presentModalViewController:pagetwo animated:YES];
```

Or if it's a subclass of UIView, you need:

```
[self.view addSubview:pagetwo];
```

But before that you need to alloc/init pagetwo (and release it later) which will be hard to do since your class is also named "pagetwo" and you instance variable can't be called the same. you could call it (the instance variable) pagetwoview or something, but preferred way would be to follow Objective-C naming conventions and ***always*** name your classes starting with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

To navigate from one view to another or to insert subview given solution is correct and following is the sample code to let you know, how to use delegate method of UIWebView **loadHTMLString:baseURL:**...

```
    NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Page 1</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H2>HTML Code Editor</H2><H3>p1 - The Basic Page</H3>"
            "<P>This is the  basic webpage. The HTML tags, BODY, H2, H4, P and A were used, but since no attributes were added to these tags, they are left at their defaults. The links below are shown using their default colors.</P>"
            "<A HREF=\"http://www.google.com\">Google.com</A><BR><A HREF=\"http://www.yahoo.com\">Yahoo</A><BR></BODY></HTML>"];
    [webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```